# How to get the order index of a structure entry?

Tags: templating, structure, order

I have a structure with 3 levels.

The first 2 levels are for structuring the content and most of the content comes from the 3.rd level.
This 3.rd level are the entries which are written by different authors.

I now want to display all entries written by a certain author.

The output i’m looking for would be like this:
2017 / 01 / 3rd Level entry title

2017 -> title of 1st level entry

01   -> Index of 2nd level entry

title -> title of 3rd level entry

I struggle with displaying the index of the 2nd level entry. I didn’t find a field in the database which stores the index of an entry.

Does anyone know how to get the index of a certain entry?

[image]